# For loop for increasing pyramid pattern

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to increment a pyramid based on input from the user.\
If a user enters the number 3, my program will print a pyramid of height 3, three times.\
What I would like it to do instead, is to print 3 pyramids, but the first pyramid should have a height of 1, and the second a height of 2, and the third a height of 3.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = scanner.nextInt();

    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {

        System.out.println("Pyramid " + n);

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print("#");
            }

            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print("#");
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < n - i; k++) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create and implement a method `printPyramid(int size)`, get it working for any `size`, then refactor your code to use it. Doing so will make your code will be much easier to understand and you will solve problems such as this quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You use `l` to keep track of the number of pyramid you're working on, so you could just use it in the loop instead of `n`. Note that `l` starts with `0`, not `1`, so you may want to amend the loop accordingly and run from `1` to `n`, not from `0` to `n-1`

```
for (int l = 1; l <= n; l++) { // Note the loop starts at 1

    System.out.println("Pyramid " + l);

    for (int i = 1; i <= l; i++) { // Note the usage of l instead on n

        for (int j = 0; j < l - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print("#");
        }

        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print("#");
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < l - i; k++) { // Note the usage of l instead on n
            System.out.print(".");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to change is this part of code

```
System.out.println("Pyramid " + (l+1));

        for (int i = 1; i <= l+1; i++) {
```